# Unable to download or very slow download of boot2docker.iso (v19.03.5) from github repo

Tags: docker, github, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

Docker newbie here.

I just installed Docker Toolbox on my Win10 (Home) machine. After installation, I'm supposed to run a "Docker Quickstart Terminal". It opens up a terminal that tries to download a "boot2docker.iso" file but it is not able to do so. It usually times out or gives me an error that says "something went wrong. Press a key to continue" and that closes the terminal. Here's the terminal.

[image]

I ended up monitoring my network logs and realised it wasn't downloading anything. So to find a workaround, I found [a comment here](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3229) that says the ISO can be downloaded [manually from here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases) and placed in the `docker/cache folder`. But when I try to download the file from my browser, the download doesn't even start.

Why can't I download this file?

1. Is this a github download issue?
2. Is there another way to download this ISO?
3. What if I don't want the latest ISO? I'm assuming it tries to download the ISO because it wants the latest. But when I run `docker --version` from my terminal, I see that I have a `v19.03.1`. That's not bad, right?
4. Even if this download works, is there a way to turn off automatic boot2docker updates on docker so I don't get stuck in the future?

Comment: I think this was related hyper V virtual switch configuration. I saw 10kb/s download speed and after I restart the machine I downloaded the iso in 30 seconds. just FYI. docker in windows 10 is so broken :) I have been trying to make it work since morning.

Comment: For anyone else who might be stuck with this; I was not able to find the main cause or resolve it completely, but I eventually had to download my files on my phone and transfer it to my laptop. I thought it might be an issue with my wi-fi (did not try w LAN) but even downloading on my laptop using a hotspot did not work so I assume this had something do with the network settings at the time.